# Filter And Order In Complex Object

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter, angularjs-orderby

I have an array of object as below:

```
$scope.clients = [
              { client: { name: 'ABC', age: '25' } },
              { client: { name: 'BCD', age: '26' } },
              { client: { name: 'CDE', age: '26' } }
            ];
```

And a filter object (actually this are bonded to **ng-model** in the **view**) to **filter** and **order** the array object:

```
 $scope.filterParams = {
                nameSearch: 'ABC',
                order: 'age'
            };
```

while i try to update the filter by `client.name` is does not found anything in the list and the `order by` also does not work :

```
 $scope.updateFilter = function () {
                var filtered;
                filtered = $filter('filter')($scope.clients, { 'client.name' : $scope.filterParams.nameSearch });
                filtered = $filter('orderBy')(filtered.client, $scope.filterParams.order);

                $scope.filteredList = filtered;
            }

 $scope.$watchCollection('filterParams', function () {
                $scope.updateFilter();
            });
```

**Can anybody here show me the right direction to filter and order the list?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function as the 2nd parameter when calling `$filter('orderBy')()`. The input parameter of the function is the item of the array to be sorted. The function returns the valued to be compared using '<', '>', '=='.

```
function(item){
          return parseInt(item.client[$scope.filterParams.order]);
}
```

Also, you are not sorting the original array `$scope.clients`, but sorting the filtered result, which is only one record. I wonder if it is an error.

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f89sq448/37/).

Comment: In my fiddle, the record with name 'ABC' has been filtered out as desired, right?